# Persistent VPN on Windows Server 2008 says local only

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, vpn

I have set-up a Persistent Connection VPN in Server Manager > Network Interfaces tab. It has been working but we have recently changed the IP address and I'm not sure if it is working anyone. The status is enabled, with state connected, but in the currently connected to, it says it is just a local connection - is that correct? Is there a good method to check the connection is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a number of tests we found the VPN was working, so the `local connection` was correct.